# How to copy data from database?

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Just the data in the tables not the tables and structure itself.

I have  cpanel hosting and have phpmyadmin and other database tools  that come with cpanel.

I tried import to sql from phpmyadminbut it gives me the whole table structure with create tables and all along with the data.

I need just the data.

Comment: no options with phpmyadmin werre suggested so i chose not to slect a right answer. phpmyadmin does provide an option to export only structure, only data or both.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info mydb`

is a way to do it through a commandline, but not sure you have access to it from cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

What format do you want the data in?

If you want it in the form of MySQL queries, you should use mysqldump, as DTest indicated.

If you want it in the form of a CSV (or something similar), you should use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Alternatively, you can even [use mysqldump to dump your tables as XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml)!